# Laravel's rename column migration altering the position of column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, database-migration

I have migration file where I am doing:

```
Schema::table('table_xyz', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('col_old_name', 'col_new_name');
});
```

Running this migration updates the `table_xyz` with the new column name, but also changes the position of the column in DB (places the column at the end)

To avoid that I did:

```
Schema::table('table_xyz', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('col_old_name', 'col_new_name')
           ->after('col_to_be_after')
});
```

This is also not yielding the desired result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this,

```php
    $table->renameColumn('col_old_name', 'col_new_name')
           ->after('col_to_be_after')
```

`renameColumn()` returns `Illuminate\Support\Fluent` but `->after()` is under `Illuminate\Database\Schema\ColumnDefinition`. So that's why you code does not work.

Without losing the data you may have to:

1. create a new one in a specific position : `$table->string('xyx')->after('qwe');`
2. copy the data from the old one to the new one.
3. delete the old col.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep data, this is one way to do it:

```
public function up()
{
    //Give the moving column a temporary name:
    Schema::table('table_xyz', function($table)
    {
        $table->renameColumn('col_new_name', 'col_old_name');
    });

    //Add a new column with the regular name:
    Schema::table('table_xyz', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->string('col_new_name')->after('col_to_be_after');
    });

    //Copy the data across to the new column:
    DB::table('table_xyz')->update([
        'col_new_name' => DB::raw('col_old_name')   
    ]);

    //Remove the old column:
    Schema::table('table_xyz', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->dropColumn('col_old_name');
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following below steps, hopefully you are missing something your code seems fine.

Remove your existing migration and add a new migration

```
 rm database/migrations/your-migration-file`
 
 php artisan make:migration rename_col_old_name_table_xyz_table --table=table_xyz
```

Add the following code in `up()` and `down()`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table_xyz', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('col_old_name', 'col_new_name');
    });
}
And down() function with this,

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('table_xyz', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->renameColumn('col_new_name', 'col_old_name');
    });
}
```

For detailed documentation, check [Renaming columns in migrations](https://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrations/#renaming-and-dropping-tables)

> Since you are renaming column then it should not add at the end, so I don't think you need add `->after('col_to_be_after')`

Comment: i didn't understand the reason for removing the migration file first time

Comment: also this is the similar thing i am doing and no good with this